# GWT-Charts (Google Visualization GWT Java Wrapper) throws exception when adding an interval column

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I'm using the GWT-Charts Java wrapper for Google Visualization tools. I'm adding interval roles but I get an exception when I add the role column:
Here's the code:

```
LineChart chart = new LineChart();
        DataTable table = DataTable.create();
        table.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Month");
        table.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales");
        DataColumn col = DataColumn.create(ColumnType.NUMBER, RoleType.INTERVAL);
        table.addColumn(col);
        return chart;
```

This throws:

```
(Error) @com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.DataTable::addColumn(Lcom/googlecode/gwt/charts/client/DataColumn;)([JavaScript object(12)]): Invalid type: function () {
      var result = __static(dispId, this);
      if (result[0]) {
        throw result[1];
      } else {
        return result[1];
      }
    }.
```

Reading the JavaDoc for the RoleType.Interval doesn't give me a warm feeling that this code has ever been used: "Text to display when the user hovers over the data point associated with this row. Data type: string Default:
     * Data point value"

That's clearly wrong. 
Has anyone here successfully used GWT-Charts and the Interval function?
Thanks!

Comment: which wrapper are you using ? The official one or the unofficial gwt-charts ?

Comment: The unofficial one. It seemed to have more recent activity and support.

Comment: I see that the role functions do not work as documented in the issues for this project. i got around it by using JNSI to directly generate JavaScript.